# To find out which emotion I'm writing in sentence, How can I make my chatbot?

Tags: ibm-watson, chatbot, watson-conversation

I'm trying to make a chatbot to ask about user's feeling on exhibition.

(with IBM watson-conversation workspace on web.)

**First, question is**

It has 7 steps asking how user's feel on exhibition.

I can make this flow with direct answer for the question.

However It doesn't work if user's answer was not what I expect.

It just goes back to the beginning.

How can I make a dialog flow to not going back steps?

**Secondly**

In these steps, I want to know how user feels at the sentence.

If I want to know that feelings at the same time, how do I make those?

I declare those word into entities, I can see them on the testing chatbot section.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Zissouu, Thanks for the comments :)
I just had that on my web workspace How can I show you my code?
Sorry if I ask you stupid question

Comment: Jeremy, you can take a screenshot of your dialog and entities(if possible) and share them here. That'll help us understand exactly how you have designed your flow.

Answer (score 2):

**For Question 1:**

Conversation service works like that. If it doesn't find the matching intent in the continuing flow, then it looks for that intent in the root node. After that also if it doesn't find the intent, then it goes to the *anything_else* intent.

One simple solution to your query is to give your users some options to choose from if it's possible. That way you'll have more control over what user can enter and simultaneously you can maintain your flow.

And if that's not possible, then try to include all possible intents in the flow, where all sorts of variation from user text can trigger the intent and the flow is maintained.

**For Question 2:**

I believe you are asking about using [Tone Analyzer service](https://www.ibm.com/watson/services/tone-analyzer/) to identify user emotions for the texts that the user entered and you probably want to direct the user to a specific flow in Conversation depending upon what emotion was detected.

Keep one thing in mind that all Watson services are independent of each other, that means one service can't identify any other services that's connected to the same application.

So when user enter the text, first give that text to Tone Analyzer from the application and once you get the response, parse the emotions and give it accordingly to Conversation service, so that proper dialog can be detected.

Comment: I'd also add to pass the related tone pieces into the context object, you can take action on the tones.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Jena. 

It will helps me much I don't think it will work to upload my images cuz they are made of my own language:(

I did this chat flow like this.


6 steps of chatbot process as intents, I listed up possible words and sentence in the intents and put emotions in enities.

Therefore I'm trying to get the steps and feelings at the sametime.

However It doesn't work smoothly, how can I make them better?
just put many sentence I can?
Is it get better if I give this to my friends and make them talk make my chat smarter?

Comment: Putting emotions into entities might not be a good solution. Because you can't just identify if someone is not happy if they only say terms like "bad service" or "pathetic product", it's much more expressive than that. One can express his anger or unhappiness simply by being rude or sarcastic about it. And that information you can't capture in the Entities of Conversation.

Comment: I would recommend using the Tone Analyzer service. You need to pass the user entered text to TA first, and whatever statistics you get from it, you can add them to the context of Conversation and then pass the same user-entered text to Conversation as well. By this, you can identify your intent and also the emotions at the same time which were stored in the context that you can access in the dialogue of the Conversation nodes by the $ character.

Comment: Thanks for your help Jena. It helps me to understand more about the chat.

Thing I do on this chat is to play some tunes match with the emotion, so It doesn't have to be perfect every single time. I looked up Tone Analyzer however It deosn't assist korean, so I think I can't use that on here:(